# Eclipse: ant exec .bat file not stopping

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, batch-file, ant

I'm using an ant build script to compile some java classes, create a .jar file and place the classes into it, and then run a batch file using ant's exec command. The .bat file uses the .jar file to execute several java classes.

The command line output from running the .bat file shows in the Eclipse output window, but when I hit the stop button in Eclipse, it doesn't stop executing. It stops showing command line output in Eclipse, but the processes controlled by the batch file will continue until it reaches the end of all processes.

Here's my ant script;

```
<project name="myProject" default="all">
<property name="app.name" value="myProject"/>

<path id="classpath">
  <fileset dir="${lib}" erroronmissingdir="false">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.properties"/>
  </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="javac" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac" classpathref="classpath"/>
<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc" classpathref="classpath"/>

<target name="prepare">
  <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${target}"/>
</target>

<!-- COMPILE -->
<target name="compile" depends="prepare">
  <delete dir="${classes}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${build}"/>

  <javac destdir="${classes}" 
         srcdir="src" 
         includes="**/*" 
         classpathref="classpath">
  </javac>

  <groovyc destdir="${classes}" 
           srcdir="src" 
           includes="**/*" 
           classpathref="classpath">
  </groovyc>    
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${target}/lib"/>
  <copy todir="${target}/lib">
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
      <exclude name="junit*"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>

  <!-- JAR -->
  <jar destfile="${target}/lib/${app.name}.jar">
  <fileset dir="${classes}">
    <include name="**/*.class"/>
  </fileset>
  </jar>

  <copy todir="${lib}">
    <fileset dir="${target}/lib">
      <include name="${app.name}.jar"/>
      <exclude name="junit*"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>

  <!-- RUN BATCH FILE -->
  <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
    <arg line="/c myBatchFile.bat"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

How can I stop this from executing, other than waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Your Ant script makes the same as when you open Windows Explorer and double click on a batch file, it starts the `cmd.exe` as new process. Therefore exiting Windows Explorer or your Ant script (or killing them) does not have any effect on the separate command line interpreter process (batch execution) already running. If you want to kill all processes started by your Ant script, it would be needed to code a task kill for the started batch task executed on termination of the Ant script. As I don't know anything about Ant scripts, I don't know if that is possible at all in Ant scripts.

Comment: What should be possible is to have another batch file with one or if necessary even more `taskkill.exe` calls to terminate the started batch file and the processes started by this batch file. This second batch file can be executed now from within Eclipse or perhaps also from within your Ant script before termination.